# Let $(B_t)$ be a Brownian motion. What is the distribution of $\int_0^t \frac{B_s-sB_1}{1-s} ds + B_t - tB_1$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $(B_t)$ be a Brownian motion. Let $0<t<1$. What is the distribution of $X_t=\int_0^t \frac{B_s-sB_1}{1-s} ds + B_t - tB_1$ ?

The tricky part is of course the integral. I do not see how to exploit the increments of the Brownian motion like one usually does when faced with integrals of Brownian motion. My intuition tells me that $X_t \sim\mathcal N (0,t)$.

Comment: Hints: Integration by parts gives
$$
\int_0^t\frac{B_s}{1-s}\,ds=\int_0^t\log(1-s)\,dB_s-\log(1-t)B_t\,
$$
which is seen to be Gaussian. The other component of the $ds$-integral is Gaussian as well:
$$
B_1\int_0^t\frac{s}{1-s}\,ds\,.
$$

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you for the hint. So now I should be able to write everything in terms of increments and use the fact that the increments are independent Gaussians and hence the sum is Gaussian? Because I still don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using integration-by-parts
$$
\int_0^t\frac{B_s}{1-s}\,ds=\int_0^t\log(1-s)\,dB_s-\log(1-t)B_t\,
$$
and
$$
B_1\int_0^t\frac{s}{1-s}\,ds
$$
and writing $f(t)=\int_0^t\frac{s}{1-s}\,ds+t$
we get that

\begin{align}
X_t&=\int_0^t1+\frac{\log(1-s)}{\log(1-t)}\,dB_s-B_1\int_0^t\frac{s}{1-s}\,ds-tB_1\\
&=\int_0^t1+\frac{\log(1-s)}{\log(1-t)}\,dB_s-f(t)B_1\\
&=\underbrace{\int_0^t1+\frac{\log(1-s)}{\log(1-t)}+f(t)\,dB_s}_{=:\,Y_t\text{ Gaussian }}-\underbrace{f(t)(B_1-B_t)}_{\text{Gaussian and independent of }Y_t}\,.
\end{align}